# Batch start with parameters Error

Tags: vb.net, process, arguments

I'm trying to make only a small program which includes the two steps decompile and start from a `.java` file. I can't run the `.bat` file correctly because DOS doesn't accept the spaces like I want.

Here's my code:

```
Process.Start("cmd.exe", "/c start "" """ & TextBoxJavacPath.Text & _
"""" & " " & """" & TextBoxFile.Text & """")
```

That's the string that comes out: (it's right)

```
/c "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\bin\javac.exe"
"C:\Users\Niklas\Desktop\Java\Kap06\src\eingabe\LetsReadLine.java"
```

If I enter it by typing in console it works, but via vb.net it doesn't work.

[image: The Program with input]

The error is the following: `The command "C:/Program" is written incorrect or couldn't be found.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this code (I don't know if it'll work) :

```
Private Sub Start(javacPath As String, file As String)
    Using p As New Process With {
        .StartInfo = New ProcessStartInfo With {
            .WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(javacPath),
            .Arguments = "/c """ & Path.GetFileName(javacPath) & """ """ & file,
            .FileName = "cmd",
            .CreateNoWindow = True}}
        p.Start()
    End Using
End Sub
```

And call the method like this :

```
Start(TextBoxJavacPath.Text, TextBoxFile.Text)
```

I can't test the code, because I don't have any `.java` file...

Comment: @NiklasTeichert You're welcome ! Don't forget to upvote and mark the answer as the best answer ;)